# Distance matrix to dist element

Tags: r

New to R here.
I have computed a distance matrix over, say, points a, b, c:

```
(a,a) = 0;
(a,b) = 1;
(a,c) = 5;
(b,a) = 1;
(b,b) = 0;
(b,c) = 7;
(c,a) = 5;
(c,b) = 7;
(c,c) = 0;
```

And I want to use a function that expects the 'dist' R element.
My distance function is the result of a computation on the items' coordinates, but it's
not a standard computation, so I can't create the dist element using the dist constructor, which expects only several predefined distance measures.

Bottom line is that I want to create the dist element out of the matrix that I have computed.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: It's still not clear to me what your question is asking for.

Comment: It also appears that your 'distance function' is not a valid distance metric - is this a concern?

Comment: @Dason, the OP's last sentance: _"Bottom line is that I want to create the dist element out of the matrix that I have computed"_  ;)

Comment: @RicardoSaporta I read that but it still wasn't clear to me.  Are they just saying they want something that has the 'dist' class?  I'm fairly sure mnel's answer is what they want but I didn't feel the question as it is stated provides a clear picture of what they actually want.  Add on top of that the fact that their example output isn't actually a distance metric and I just wasn't comfortable saying that I understood their intention...

Comment: @Dason, you have a good point. There is a bit of fuzziness, and it's definitely not a matrix.   Some questions are harder to interpret than others.  As you say, it looks like mnel's answer is on the money

Comment: Hi again. Sorry for the fuzziness. I meant that I want the dist element to contain exactly the values in the symmetric matrix, rather than values that are computed based on these values.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a distance class object from a matrix

Just create the matrix and use `as.dist`

eg

```
 as.dist(matrix( c(0, 1, 5, 1, 0, 7, 5, 7, 0), ncol=3))


  1 2
2 1  
3 5 7
```